# Add new item to appropriate place in a sorted array using jQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using C# and ASP.NET MVC3. I have a javascript array that I'm creating when the page loads based on some data:

```
var agencyData = [];
@foreach(var agency in Model.Agencies)
{
    <text>agencyData.push({value: '@agency.AgencyID', label: '@agency.Name'});</text>                    
}
```

This array is sorted alphabetically by `label`.

I have functionality on the page that will add an item to this array. Unfortunately it adds it to the end of the array. I'd like to add the item to the appropriate spot in the array so that the array remains sorted alphabetically.

Also, the array is huge, like 8000 items. So I don't think resorting the array after every addition would be a good option.

Anyone have a good idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

find an appropriate index for new element (use [dichotomic search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichotomic_search))

slice and concat arrays

```
var agencyData = ["alpha", "beta", "gamma"];

var calculateIndexForInsertion = function(text, start, end){
    //add real search here
    return 2;
}
var newAgency = "c";

var index = calculateIndexForInsertion(newAgency , 0, agencyData.length);

agencyData = agencyData.slice(0, index).concat([newAgency]).concat(agencyData.slice(index))
```

Comment: Why not `splice` though?

Comment: @AndreyShchekin because slice works just fine... If you think splice is better, and it is confirmed by benchmarks/memory profiling - it could be true; I admit, I've never compared. Just because slice works fine. For 8000 points - I don't belive it's going to make a difference (while I can be wrong, of course)

Comment: My point is that you do not have to do two slices -- you can do one `splice` at the `index` to insert the new item. Basically `agencyData.splice(index, 0, newAgency)`.